# Enabling Session State in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I'd like to use session variables in my ASP.NET MVC application.

I already added the `<sessionState>` tag in my `web.config` file like this

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
    </sessionState>
```

I get a session ID in my url like this if I use `cookieless="true"`

```
http://localhost:2967/%28S%28hcawmi55zoruuy453fbo3k55%29%29/RmdReqBankAccount
```

But I still can't use session variables in my application.

I set the variable like this in my login method:

```
Session["username"] = userName;
```

and I retrieve it like this

```
string user_id = (string)Session["username"];
```

I get an empty string when trying to retrieve values.

Comment: Are cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: yes Dimitrov , cookies are enabled

Comment: Why did you make it a community wiki question?

Comment: Do you get an empty string or a null? Where are you setting/getting the session value? In an action? In the constructor?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fixed , it seems I got the wrong location when writing the set session variables.