# TempData not passing object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public  async Task<ActionResult> AddBookingCreditCard(TripViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do nothing right now
    }

    TempData["ccInfo"] = model.CcInfo;
    return RedirectToAction("Book", new{ id = model.Trip.TripId, travellers = model.Travellers});
}
```

In this case, model.CcInfo DOES exist and contains an object of type CcInfo. After the RedirectToAction, this method is called:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Book(int id, int travellers)
{
    var vm = new TripViewModel();
    vm.Travellers = travellers;

    if (TempData["ccInfo"] != null)
        vm.CcInfo = TempData["ccInfo"] as CcInfo;

    // lot of code

    return View("Index", vm);
}
```

The if-statement always fails: TempDate["ccInfo"] is null, while it should contain my object.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The CcInfo class:

```
public class CcInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "Name on Card"), Required]
    public string CcName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card Number"), DataType(DataType.CreditCard), Required]
    public int CcNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Card CVV"), Required, Range(100, 999)]
    public int CcCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are both the methods in the same controller ??

Comment: What is your session state provider? TempData is relying on a Session.

Comment: Ehh, no idea, so I guess I'm using the default..

Comment: ok. 'TempData' is mostly used to pass data between two different controller. You can you just put the value in Session["ccInfo"] to see if the value is persisting in both the methods...

Comment: Have you checked that the value of `model.CcInfo` is not actually null when you add it to `TempData`?

Comment: It's not working with Session either. And yes, I'm sure model.CcInfo is not null.

Comment: Can you pass one more parameter   RedirectToAction("Book", new{ id = model.Trip.TripId, travellers = model.Travellers, ccInfo = model.CcInfo});  to the method and check is it getting the value ??

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried (before using TempData) and that's not working either :(

Comment: I think your model is not passing CCInfo .

Comment: But I'm 100% sure model.CcInfo contains an object as I've checked this several times...

Comment: then how other values of the parameters are getting passed. if you can pass the value of model.Trip.TripId in Session["TripID"] and check in the method , is it getting passed.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it has something to do with using async? Is this possible?

Comment: Yup, just passing an id in Session DOES work. I've added my CcInfo class to the OP.

Comment: `TempData` I have always known only to persist data from the `Action` to the `View` page. Not form action to action.

Comment: But it works when just passing an id, so it works. A lot of examples on the internet are doing exactly the same. Something is wrong with the object causing it not to pass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your issue, and I can spot the problem.

This code works fine for me:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddBookingCreditCard()
    {
        TempData["ccInfo"] = "Hell world";
        return RedirectToAction("Book", new { id = 1, travellers = 2 });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Book(int id, int travellers)
    {
        var vm = new object();

        if (TempData["ccInfo"] != null)
        {
            vm = new object();
        }

        // lot of code
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

However, if I change AddBookingCreditCard to recieve POST requests only:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddBookingCreditCard()
```

Then the `TempData` dictionary is empty.

To cut to the chase, you need to use session state for storing items between requests in your case.

I don't recall the exact details, but I think TempData does work well for situations where you need to redirect to another controller action, but only if it's within a GET request. Coming from a POST and then redirecting to a GET seems to wipe TempData to a clean slate, which makes sense, as TempData is for that scenario only I believe (please feel free to correct me on that).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Session doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have session state enabled in `web.config`? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620520/enabling-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Adding this to my web.config gives me an "unknown" Internal Server Error.

Comment: Okay, I got that fixed. It's not passing the correct data, thank you very much! One more problem: my ValidationMessageFor is not showing the error it should display...

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant "now" instead of "not". So it's now passing the parameter! I now only have the problem with the validation..

Comment: Congrats on fixing your problem :) OK, regards your query with `ValidationMessageFor`, I suggest you ask a new StackOverflow question specifically for that.